# Django Auth , Login Question

Tags: python, django, session, authentication

**Question Clarification:**
I'm trying to test if the user is authenticated or not for each page request.

I'm trying to use Authentication for the first time in Django and I am not grasping how the login view is supposed to handle authentications.

When I use @login_required, I'm redirecting to "/login" to check if the user is logged in and if not, display the login page.  However, trying to redirect back to the original page is causing an infinite loop because it's sending me back to the login page over and over again.

I'm clearly not grasping how @login_required is supposed to work but I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I've been searching around for awhile for an example, but everyone uses the default @login_required without the 'login_url' parameter.

So for example.. the page I'm trying to access would be...

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def index(request):
```

And then my login would be.. (obviously incomplete)..

Edit: just to note.. the session variables are set in another view

```
def login(request):
    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:

        # just for testing purposes.. to make sure the id is being set
        print "id:",request.session['_auth_user_id']

        try:
            user = Users.objects.get(id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
        except:
            raise Exception("Invalid UserID")

        # TODO: Check the backend session key

        # this is what I'm having trouble with.. I'm not sure how
        # to redirect back to the proper view
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

        return render_to_response('login.html',
            {'form':form},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using [django.contrib.auth.views.login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)?

Comment: Excuse me, but where your user does login action? I mean where called method *login* to login him?

Comment: @isbadawi Thank you.  That's what I was looking for...  partially anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you say, obviously that's not going to work, because it's incomplete. So, until you complete it, you're going to get an infinite loop - because you haven't written the code that puts `_auth_user_id` into request.session.

But I don't really know why you're making that test in the first place. The [auth documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in) has a perfectly good example of how to write a login view: get the username and password from the form, send them to `authenticate` to get the user object, then pass that to `login`... done.

**Edit** I *think* I might see where your confusion is. The `login_required` decorator itself does the check for whether the user is logged in - that's exactly what it's for. There's no need for you to write any code to do that. Your job is to write the code that actually logs the user in, by calling `authenticate` and `login`.

Comment: That's not really what I'm having trouble with.. I'm trying to test if the user is authenticated or not for each request.

Comment: Er... what? If the user isn't authenticated, then the `login_required` decorator will redirect them to a login view, which you write as shown in my link.

Comment: You do not login your user indeed.

Comment: "The login_required decorator itself does the check for whether the user is logged in - that's exactly what it's for"... was what I was looking for.  I didn't note the "user_passes_test" check in that and I've got some custom stuff going on behind the scenes so it looks like I'll need to write my own login_required decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call login(), see the next please:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login